Archivo JSP no existe
buen dia , lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de incluir un jsp en otro jsp en jakarta ee con java 17 ,pero al momento de incluirla me marca error , el error me dice que el archivo header.jsp no existe pero si tengo creado el archivo y esta en la ruta indicada:

    <jsp:include page="layout/header.jsp" />
<h3>${title}</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active">Menu de opciones</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/productos">mostrar productos html</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login.html">login</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">logout</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/carro/ver">ver carro</a></li>
</ul>

<jsp:include page="layout/footer.jsp"/>

¿Saben porque me dice que no existe el archivo header.jsp ?
Este es el error que me da:


Te diría que es un problema con la ruta del header.jsp, seguramente no este bien puesta.
